# Is there a way to access variables from an imported gradle script?

Tags: gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file that's fairly long, and I'd like to break some of the logic up into smaller files to make the whole thing more maintainable.  After moving some tasks into a new file, I found that none of the variables I had set in the parent script were available in the child script.  Below is a pair of source files I reproduced this behavior with:

build.gradle:

```
apply from: 'repro.gradle'

def foo = "This is a variable"

tasks.register('printFromMainScript') {
    println(foo)
}
```

repro.gradle:

```
tasks.register('printFromChildScript') {
    println(foo)
}
```

In the above example, `printFromMainScript` works fine, but `printFromChildScript` fails.  Is there a way to access `foo` from `repro.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def foo` creates a variable that exists only in the scope of `build.gradle`. [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:declaring_variables) explains this more in detail.

There is `ext` block in Gradle which is meant for extra properties.

This should work in your case:

build.gradle:

```
apply from: 'repro.gradle'

ext {
  foo = "This is a variable"
}
```

repro.gradle:

```
task printFromChildScript {
    doLast {
      println(project.foo)
    }
}
```

Note: `doLast` block ensures that the `println` function is called only when the project is fully configured and `printFromChildScript` is actually executed. If you put `println` directly in task body then it will be executed during Gradle project configuration phase.

Comment: I should be able to work with that, since the variables don't need to be used in the configuration phase.  Thank you!